# How can I mantain the hidden columns in proper table when I change the combo

Tags: javascript

I have different tables with different names and in each of those tables I have a combo with different **option value**.
In each table I have a button that allows to hide one or more columns.
The goal is to mantain the hidden columns also when I change the combo.

I tried to use this code:

```js
var options = document.querySelectorAll('option');

// Filter out the ones that have the "LRSYSCPU" substring

var filtered = [...options].filter(({ value }) => value);

// Return those option values
var values = filtered.map(({ value }) => value);

var columns_to_hide = [];
$("input.colman-cbox").each(function(idx, val) {
    var $$ = $(val);
    if (!$$.attr('checked')) {
        columns_to_hide.push($$.attr('value'));
    }
});


// values.forEach(function(element) {
for (index = 0; index < values.length; ++index) {
    var MyTblId = values[index];
    if (CheckIfChrome()) {
        try {
            localStorage.removeItem(MyTblId);
            localStorage.setItem(MyTblId, columns_to_hide);
        } catch (ex) {};
    } else {
        if ($.cookie(MyTblId)) {
            $.cookie(MyTblId, '', { path: '/' });
        }
        $.cookie(MyTblId, columns_to_hide, {
            expires: 10000,
            path: '/'
        });
    }
};
```

In this way I use a loop that creates a cookie foreach option value in order to mantain the hidden columns when I change the combo.

It works, but because I take all the OPTION VALUE of my html page the problem is that it effects all the table, while I want that it affect just the table I clicked the button.

The problem is that I don't have an identifier in the option value that distinguishes one table from another.
The identifier is just in the **NAME** see the code below:

```html
<TABLE>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <A CLASS="TOP" NAME="MRRMFBSY" HREF="#TOP" title="Top">
    </TD>
    <TD>
      <SELECT onChange="chData(this,this.value)">
        <OPTION VALUE=MIPS1>MIPS
        <OPTION VALUE=MSU1>MSU
        <OPTION VALUE=PERCEN1>% CEC
        <OPTION VALUE=NUMGCP1>nCPU
      </SELECT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

How can I create an association between the option value and the NAME?
The NAME is dynamic and I need to distinguish the option value of the single tables I have. I cannot put an identifier in the OPTION VALUE (maybe it would be the best option, but I can't).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the HTML code coming from? It looks like IE5 contenteditable ...

Comment: Is this a destructured object...: `(({ value }) => value);`? How does that work? If it is valid syntax how is it different and/or better than: `((value, index) => value);` ?

Comment: What do you mean "coming from"? I opened with chrome the HTTML page and the i see the source frame

Comment: The click event of the button tells you which button was clicked. So if you navigate from that button up the DOM tree until you get the table, you can use `table.querySelectorAll( 'option' )` instead of `document.querySelectorAll( 'option' )`, so that you only get the options inside the table the button is in. Personally I would stucture everything differently, but that should fix your issue of having all the options instead of only the related ones.

Comment: @Shiilli Tank you. I will try it and  I will let you know

Comment: @zer00ne . Maybe I'm reading it wrong, but `var options` gets you a nodeList. `var filtered` then creates an array from it. So inside the array are DOM nodes. So `(({ value }) => value);` destructures `element.value`. And hence `((value, index) => value);` would have to be `((value, index) => value.value );` or better `((option, index) => option.value);`.

Comment: @Shilly ah so it is destructured, thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but how can I get the NAME NAME="MRRMFBSY" if I know that the TABLE ID="MIPS"?

Comment: You can use `.querySelector()` for that as well: `table.querySelector( '*[name="MRRMFBSY"]' );` Basically meaning: select the first element of any type that has an attribute name with the value "MRRMFBSY". The same can be done using JQuery: `$();` with the same selector. Almost all the selectors that work in JQuery, also work in `.querySelector()`.

Comment: Or do you Not have the value MRRMFBSY and the question is how to get it? What do you have then you can work with? Do you know that the element containing that name will always be an `<a>` tag in the first cell of the table?

Comment: I have thid code:

Comment: The code is below... as you can see I have the name in the A CLASS ="TOP"

Comment: Please use more descriptive title for your issue (if you have better idea for the title feel free to change it)

Answer (score 0):

```
<TABLE><TR><TD>
<A CLASS="TOP" NAME="MRRMFBSY" HREF="#TOP" 
 title="Top"> 
<IMG SRC="..\..\IMG\TOP.PNG"></A>
<A CLASS="PREVDAY" HREF=..\D08FEB18\MRMF.X88D5.D08FEB18.HTML#MRRMFBSY
 title="Previous Day"> 
<IMG SRC="..\..\IMG\PREVDAY.PNG"></A>
</TD><TD CLASS=HD3>RMFINT CPU UTILIZATION </TD>
<TD><A CLASS="NEXTDAY" HREF=..\D10FEB18\MRMF.X88D5.D10FEB18.HTML#MRRMFBSY
 title="Next Day"> 
<IMG SRC="..\..\IMG\NEXTDAY.PNG"></A>
<A ID=AFMRRMFBSY
 CLASS="CALEN" HREF=../DXXXXXXX/MRMF.X88D5.DXXXXXXX.HTML#MRRMFBSY
 title="Navigation Calendar"> 
<IMG SRC="..\..\IMG\CALENDAR.PNG" ></A>
</TD><TD></TD>
<TD><SELECT onChange="chData(this,this.value)"> 
<OPTION VALUE=MIPS1 >MIPS
<OPTION VALUE=MSU1 >MSU
<OPTION VALUE=PERCEN1 >% CEC
<OPTION VALUE=NUMGCP1 >nCPU
</SELECT></TD>
</TR></TABLE>
```

Comment: i don't know the name so i need to get it from the class TOP